# Is it usual to delete actual record, or switch "the undisplay flag" when designing database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, permissions

Sometimes you are required to keep your log and records for criminal prevention purpose.
When you give users the permission to delete record, it means that you'll lose evidences.
In ordinary cases, do you actually delete record? or switch the undisplay flag to keep log?

Comment: Of course, if you switch the undisplay flag, it takes time to exclude those records and show every time when it renders. which way is smart???

Comment: on a system with FINE GRAINED SECURITY (ROW LEVEL SECURITY) you set a policy and the exclusion becomes automatic.

Comment: Do you usually take this pattern to exclude records to display? or delete them? Obviously, all the logs and evidences will be required for the big service in order to do tracking. I just wanna know about ordinary cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you allow any modification to data then you will lose evidence.  Maybe you should design your database so you never use `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, only `INSERT`.

Unless the government has told you to keep all records, I recommend not going too much out of your way to do it.

Comment: The way to audit what happened is to produce an audit log. Don't just retain all data forever because you might need it later. As an example of a potential problem, imagine if you have a uniqueness constraint violation that cannot be resolved because you never actually delete the physical record.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is very interesting topic to discuss about.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from keeping records for auditing purposes as you mention, the use of a 'Deleted' flag also allows you to incorporate 'undo' functionality.

If you physically delete data, then it will be quite a bit of work to get the old data back. But if you use flags then it can be as easy as re-setting the flag to get the data to re-appear.

If a lot of deletes happen in your database, then the downside of flags is that you will be holding on to a lot of data that isn't being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead of just deleting is first insert the record into a history table for any type of modification that happens. Then you will always have the data available without having needless information in your main table